# RAID5-4 devices with 2 failed devices: hope to retrieve data?

Tags: linux, grub2, hard-disk, lvm, raid5

I built a RAID5 array with 4 2Tb devices a few month ago.
- I used LVM2 to build partitions.
- I also used GRUB2.
- Finally I installed Debian.
For an unknown reason the RAID failed.
The BIOS "see" only two devices.
 I am aware that my RAID is lost.
For the two failed devices smart tool return nothing.

1) with the reduced RAID array:

- is it possible to retrieve logical volumes and backup them ?
- is it possible to separate them, I mean to have two devices and not one RAID of two devices, and retrieve data ?

2) When I try to boot with the two good devices, **grub rescue** takes the control.
The **ls** command gives:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1) (md/0)
```

ls .../boot gives **unknown filesystem**
ls (md/0) gives **error disk 'md/0' not found**.

3) I boot an old device and install on it the HDDsupertool application.
This application detects the failed disk by the command:
**hddsupertool -d**

```
ata1 - cff0 cf7e cfa0 1 wdc2003FYYS-02w0b1
```

But this application is complicate and I don't know if I could retrieve data.
Any ideas I could retrieve data or repair RAID ...

Thanks

Comment: The problem is, for a four-drive RAID five configuration, the data are striped across three disks, so you're going to be missing a third of everything.

Comment: I ask myself if really both disks are ko. the probability is low. that's why I search also a solution in this direction ...

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your BIOS or motherboard rather than a hardware failure of the drives themselves.  If `hddsupertool` can see the 'failed' drive, then so can the linux kernel (try booting with a rescue CD or USB stick).  If the kernel can see the drive, then the RAID array can be re-assembled and the data retrieved - (you should immediately copy the data to somewhere else!).  I recommend installing all of the drives on another motherboard - or simply replacing your motherboard.

Comment: I tried to boot an old hdd by moving it in each slot and the boot was always correct. hddsupertool sees it as an IDE disk, uses the direct io mode. I would see rather a problem with the s.m.a.r.t data (hddsupertool does not see them).

Comment: does `blkid` or `lsblk` show the drives?  if yes, then the kernel sees them and the RAID  array can be re-assembled (and the data copied!) as i mentioned earlier.

Comment: lsblk -a sees sr0 (cdrom), sda (sda1,sda2,sda5) = my old disk, and loop0 to loop7 of loop type. blkid gives /dev/sda1 ext3 and /dev/sda5 swap and nothing else. All commands based on the device name (/dev/sdax) could not work if the BIOS hasn't detected them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a RAID5 device with 2 failed disks, you will only be able to recover bits and pieces of the device. In this case, ⅔ of the blocks would be recoverable. If there is some really important piece of data that you hope to recover and that's small enough to fit in a single RAID stripe, then with a fairly large amount of effort you can see if you can scan for it block-by-block (no guarantees), but that's about it. You will have little luck recovering any kind of intelligible filesystem. Sorry.

Comment: bad news. scan with hexdump ?

Comment: @Bertaud something like that :-(

Comment: Someone on internet used hexdump /dev/sda1 -C | grep 'LABELONE' : is it possible to find the beginning of an LV ?

Comment: Well, you'll have about a ⅔ chance of finding anything you look for, so yes, maybe. But what will you do once you find the beginning of one of the LVs? With ⅓ of its contents outright missing it will be too far gone to `fsck` or `mount`.